# What's the best way to reference code over and over?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, function

Just as an example, say I'd like to reference a msgbox in multiple areas, could I create a function for this? Private or Public? Differences?

Here's an example.

```
Public Function Message() As String
   MsgBox("Test Message")
End Function
```

Also, why would I get the following message: `Function 'Message' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used`

It seems as though its just a warning and it seemed to work when I called the function.

Comment: Make it Public Sub Message() and the error will go away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it  `Sub` so it's not expecting a return value.

```
Public Sub Message() As String
   MsgBox("Test Message")
End Sub
```